# Spring Securit + Graphql ( Spring 3.2.2)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-graphql

I am using spring for both security and graphql,

First I want to quote this from spring graphql documentation '*The path to a Web GraphQL endpoint can be secured with HTTP URL security to ensure that only authenticated users can access it.*'

So I have created a normal spring security configuration and tested it on a dummy controller, and all went well.

When I tried it on @QueryMapping
I am receiving 403 with no error message.

I have tried to debug, but there is an authorization check that is failing due to the context having a **user anonymous** instead of the one I have injected in my security filter.

I have fixed it by putting .permitAll() for /graphql and using aop to  validate my request, but is it a bug or a expected behavior?

Have a look on my Security (it was just the same but without the graphql permitall)

```
@Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
      // Enable CORS and disable CSRF
      // Setup authorization
      .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
        .requestMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/graphql/**").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/**").hasRole("LOGIN")
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated())
      .sessionManagement(session -> session
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
      ).addFilterBefore(
        this.jwtTokenFilter,
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class
      )
      .cors(cors -> cors.disable())
      .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
      .build();
```

UPDATE: I found out what is exactly the issue, the resolver (@QueryMapping) is being wrapped by a completableFuture ( internally ) post run the completable future is clearing the context, and then another internal filter checks the authorities but found that the context has been replaced by an anonymous context and it returns 403.

Comment: Could you share how your request looks like.

Comment: you have set `.anyRequest().authenticated())` but you havnt defined __how__ you want to authenticate, for instance BASIC authentication, or FormLogin etc.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add a missing part ( it is there already, will update the code snippet) @Toerktumlare

Comment: query GET_BANK_ACCOUNT {
    bankAccount(id: "df873687-e314-4b03-9f70-19581ce5e7e4") {
     id
     currency
        createdOn
        createdAt
        client {
            firstName
            lastName
        }
    }
} @Dicksonthedeveloper I have been testing this github repo but migrated from kickstart dependency to use only spring graphql https://github.com/philip-jvm/learn-spring-boot-graphql

Comment: Pls dont post code in comments, use the edit button on your question.

Comment: can you reproduce the issue with Spring Boot 3.2.3?